# How do I track ul changing and passing li into a select tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<ul>` with multiple `<li>` that can be added more or subtract less. I want those `<li>` to be able to track and put on a select multiple so I can pass them into my controller, I'm working with Razor in ASP.NET Core. The problem is I can't pass them into my selection since I don't know how to trigger the function/event whenever the item inside `<ul>` changing. The `<ul>` is generated by `InvokeAsync` to a different Component so I can't grab them directly but must interfere from my local razor page.

My HTML:

```
<ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
   <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="(1098)TH.FA02-Crushing Machine" data-select2-id="101"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>(1098)TH.FA02-Crushing Machine</li>
   <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="(1097)TH.FA02-Juicing Machine" data-select2-id="102"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>(1097)TH.FA02-Juicing Machine</li>
   <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="(1097)TH.FA02-Harvesting Machine" data-select2-id="103"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>(1097)TH.FA02-Harvesting Machine</li>
   <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="searchbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;"></li>
</ul>

<select asp-for="MachineModel.MachineProduct" hidden multiple id="selectHidden"></select>
```

My JS:

```
$('.select2-selection__rendered').click(function () {
   $('#selectHidden').empty();
   $('.select2-selection__rendered li').each(function () {
       $('#selectHidden').add(new Option($(this).attr('title'), $(this).attr('data-select2-id')));
   });
});
```

Comment: If you need to react to DOM changes triggered by scripting that is outside of your direct control, then you should use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Answer (score 0):

i used like that everytime, this must be help to you;

```
$('#selectHidden').append('<option value="'+valueFromEach+'" data-select2-id="'+idFromEach+'"></option>')
```

Comment: The problem I have is the generated 'ul' can't even trigger the click function. So I can't go any further to pass data.

Comment: oh sorry, you can try this :)
$(this).on('click','.select2-selection__rendered',function(){
//bla bla bla
})

Comment: Okay. Your way is almost working now. It just that when I click that ul, a list of items will be dropped and I have to choose an item to add as a new 'li'. All of the items have the same class. So if I set the class to be on click, they won't trigger, but if I set the class to be the ul holder, then it will only trigger before I add the item, thus making the latest item always left out. How can I overcome this, please? Or something trigger when the ul holder content is change is also okay.